# How to "package" some modules to jars and others to wars in multi-module build with single task?

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly, xsbt-web-plugin

I use `package` task (from [xsbt-web-plugin](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin)) to package a project to a war, and `assembly` task (from [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly)) to package the project to a jar.

I have a multi-module build and some modules are packaged into wars and some into jars.

I'd like to set up the build to execute `assembly` task and:

- Jar modules are packaged into jar files
- War modules are packaged into war files

How to execute `package` task for the war projects while executing `assembly` task?

Comment: Could you simply make `assembly` depend on the `package` task for each webapp project? see: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Detailed-Topics/Tasks.html#dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Both `package` task and `assembly` task evaluate to `File` type, so as @James commented you should be able to rewire `assembly` task in webapp project to run `package` instead.

```scala
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  scalaVersion := "2.11.4"
)
lazy val webappAssembly = Seq(
  assembly := packageWar.value
)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  aggregate(app, webapp).
  settings(commonSettings: _*)

lazy val app = (project in file("app")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*)

lazy val webapp = (project in file("webapp")).
  settings(commonSettings ++ jetty() ++ webappAssembly: _*).
  settings(
    libraryDependencies += "javax.servlet" % "javax.servlet-api" % "3.0.1" % "provided"
  )
```